# Style pseudo-before of disabled peer-based checkbox in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

Basically the following cannot be overwritten when the checkbox is disabled:

```
peer-checked:border-pink-500
disabled:peer-checked:border-gray-500

peer-checked:before:bg-pink-500
disabled:peer-checked:before:bg-gray-500
```

Please find the full checkbox at Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/rFx2H80DG5

I assumed the pseudo-state disabled will overwrite the styles for the pseudo peers colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled:` variant applies to the element the class is on, whereas it seems you're after the styling when the **peer** is disabled. To do this, consider using `peer-disabled` like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="absolute flex h-full w-full content-center justify-center bg-slate-900">
  <div class="inline-flex items-center">
    <div class="relative inline-block h-4 w-8 cursor-pointer rounded-full">
      <input id="switch-component" type="checkbox" checked disabled class="peer absolute h-4 w-8 cursor-pointer appearance-none rounded-full bg-blue-100 transition-colors duration-300 checked:bg-pink-500 disabled:checked:bg-gray-500 peer-checked:border-pink-500 peer-checked:before:bg-pink-500 disabled:peer-checked:border-gray-500 disabled:peer-checked:before:bg-gray-500" />
      <label for="switch-component" class="before:content[''] peer-disabled:before:bg-gray-500 absolute -left-1 top-2/4 h-5 w-5 -translate-y-2/4 cursor-pointer rounded-full border border-blue-100 bg-white shadow-md transition-all duration-300 before:absolute before:left-2/4 before:top-2/4 before:block before:h-10 before:w-10 before:-translate-x-2/4 before:-translate-y-2/4 before:rounded-full before:bg-blue-500 before:opacity-0 before:transition-opacity hover:before:opacity-10 disabled:before:bg-gray-500 peer-checked:translate-x-full peer-checked:border-pink-500 peer-checked:before:bg-pink-500 peer-disabled:border-gray-500">
        <div class="left-2/4 top-2/4 inline-block -translate-x-2/4 -translate-y-2/4 rounded-full p-5"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```